# Get pasted text DataTransferItem size

Tags: javascript, html, paste

I have a panel that accepts text paste events, this is how it works for Chrome, after some simplifications:

```
var event = e.browserEvent;
    if (event.clipboardData) {
        if (event.clipboardData.items) {
            var item = event.clipboardData.items[0]
            item.getAsString(function (e) {
                if (e) {
                    me.showText(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I'll try to paste some large amount of text, like **100MB**, the browser will freeze on item.getAsString(). So I want to add some size limit, but I couldn't find the way to do it, since item (typeof = DataTransferItem) seems to doesn't have anything like 'size', and the callback for item.getAsString() is never called. Could you please suggest a way to do it?